# Aptana Studio 3 Launch Error - Failed to load the JNI shared library "YOUR SYSTEM PATH OF JAVA...bin\server\jvm.dll"

Tags: java, windows, aptana3

My PC's environment is :

OS : windows 7 x64
JDK : 1.8.0_40

When I installed Aptana 3 Studio  and launched it, I got this message.

So I googled that sentence and I found out that somehow Aptana 3 needed x32 version of java virtual machine.

Here's what I suggest,

1. Download x32 version of jdk and install.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

2. Open file "AptanaStudio3.ini"

3.Edit it with notepad++ or any texteditor(notepad++ recommended)

-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\javaw.exe 
(javaw.exe's path should be depending on where it is actually in your PC)
(Find the path where you installed x32 jdk or jre and replace string marked as blue)

Put strings above just before "-vmargs" and re-launch it.

Done.

Comment: I can't see the question in here - have the steps you've taken resolved the issue for you?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add break line as follows:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
```

Comment: you dont need to add names like @Afef Mokhtari, they will automatically notified. i would say add as much description so that all facing the issue can get help :)

Comment: That did not work for me