# Aptana Studio 3 Launch Error - Java problems

Tags: aptana3

When first launching Aptana I got error:

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run AptanaStudio3. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
%appdata%\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\jre\bin\javaw.exe
javaw.exe in your current PATH
```

So I added Java to my PATH. Then I got:

```
Failed to load the JNI shared library "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\server\jvm.dll".
```

How to get Aptana running?

---

<sub>Note: I am aware of [Aptana Studio 3 Launch Error - Failed to load the JNI shared library "YOUR SYSTEM PATH OF JAVA...bin\server\jvm.dll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745407/aptana-studio-3-launch-error-failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-your-syste) but does not contain a question, whatismore, it is protected.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem you need to install a **32-bit** version of Java JDK.

Then either add it to you system path, or add it to `%appdata%\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\AptanaStudio3.ini` (assuming default install directory), using the [format by Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45911318/2484903) (regard line breaks!):

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install both jdk 1.7 & 1.8 (x86) according to what your Aptana version needs.
Then add in the ini file:

-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk\bin
-vmargs

You do not need to specify the file name, just indicate the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem that none of previous answers solved.
Despite the .ini modification, Aptana was still trying to get java dlls from windows system PATH variable, thus overriding AptanaStudio3.ini setup (quite unexpected behavior indeed).
To fix it I had not only to create a new entry in System Variables Path but to move it up on top of the already existing 64 bit java path entry. That worked for me.

[image]